# Feels impossible to remove the whitespace below the footer

Tags: html, css, sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUjZj.jpg)This is the html code i have written for the index.html or home page. I have used sass code to compile it into the css . I tried everything i could find on the internet related to how to get rid of white space but nothing helped and i don't want to use sticky footer or keep its position set to fixed.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <link
                rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
                integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
            />

            <link
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis&display=swap"
                rel="stylesheet"
            />

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

            <title>John | UI/UX Designer & Photographer</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--header--> 
            <header id="header-home">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav id="main-nav">
                        <h2><a href="home.html">the deck</a></h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Work.html">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="header-content">
                        <h1>
                            I am John The
                            <span
                                class="txt-type"
                                data-wait="3000"
                                data-words='["Photographer", "Designer", "UI/UX Developer"]'
                            ></span>
                        </h1>
                        <p class="lead">I specialize in UI and Photography</p>
                        <a href="work.html" class="btn-light">View My Work</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
    //These all the contents of the html page divided everything into sections A,B,C...respectively.
            <!--SECTION A SPECIALIZE -->
            <section id="home-a" class="text-center py-2">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="section-title">I SPECIALIZE IN</h2>
                    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
                    <p class="lead">
                        Photography as well as creating digital masterpieces and UI/UX layouts
                        for websites and mobile applications
                    </p>

                    <div class="specials">
                        <div>
                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-2x"></i>
                            <h3>Concepting</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet
                                beatae, omnis ipsa voluptates labore aperiam placeat, nostrum
                                nulla alias dignissimos?
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fas fa-desktop fa-2x"></i>
                            <h3>UI/UX</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet
                                beatae, omnis ipsa voluptates labore aperiam placeat, nostrum
                                nulla alias dignissimos?
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fas fa-object-ungroup fa-2x"></i>
                            <h3>VISUAL DESIGN</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet
                                beatae, omnis ipsa voluptates labore aperiam placeat, nostrum
                                nulla alias dignissimos?
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i>
                            <h3>INTERACTION</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet
                                beatae, omnis ipsa voluptates labore aperiam placeat, nostrum
                                nulla alias dignissimos?
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!--SECTION B STATS-->
            <section id="home-b" class="text-center py-2">
                <div class="stats">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-users fa-3x"></i></li>
                            <li class="stats-title">Clients</li>
                            <li class="stats-numbers">100</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-award fa-3x"></i></li>
                            <li class="stats-title">Awards</li>
                            <li class="stats-numbers">3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-hourglass-start fa-3x"></i></li>
                            <li class="stats-title">Hours Worked</li>
                            <li class="stats-numbers">3500</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-code-branch fa-3x"></i></li>
                            <li class="stats-title">Projects Completed</li>
                            <li class="stats-numbers">100</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
                <!-- SECTION C MY CREATIVE PROCESS -->
                <section id="home-c" class="text-center py-2">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2 class="section-title">
                            MY CREATIVE PROCESS
                        </h2><div class="bottom-line"></div>
                        <p class="lead">All of my UI/UX and design projects are based off of a practiced                                                                 
                         formula to get the result that I am looking for

                        </p>
                        <div class="process">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-4x process-icon my-2">
                                    <div class="process-step">1</div>
                                </i>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <h3>DISCUSS THE PROJECT
                                </h3>
                                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi voluptate 
                                 earum quaerat itaque officia soluta?
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <i class="fas fa-desktop fa-4x process-icon my-2">
                                    <div class="process-step">2</div>
                                </i>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <h3>BRAINSTORMING ^ CONCEPT

                                </h3>
                                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi voluptate 
                                earum quaerat itaque officia soluta?
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <i class="fas fa-object-ungroup fa-4x process-icon my-2">
                                    <div class="process-step">3</div>
                                </i>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <h3>UI/UX PLANNING

                                </h3>
                                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi voluptate 
                                earum quaerat itaque officia soluta?
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-4x process-icon my-2">
                                    <div class="process-step">4</div>
                                </i>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <h3>INTERACTION
                                </h3>
                                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi voluptate 
                                earum quaerat itaque officia soluta?
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>

                <!-- FOOTER -->
                <footer id="main-footer">
                    <div class="footer-content container">
                        <p>Copyright © 2019. All Rights Reserved

                        </p>
                        <div class="social">
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                            <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>

            <script src="js/typewriter.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I have used sass in the making of this website and all the code related to it is here.

```
    @import "config";
    @import "utilities";
    @import "item_grid";

    //GENERAL STYLES
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #main {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        flex-direction: column;

        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.6;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $dark-color;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    h2,
    h3,
    h4 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    //LOGO
    #logo {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    //MAIN NAV
    #main-nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 1rem;

        ul {
            display: flex;
        }

        li {
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            border-bottom: 3px transparent solid;
            padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
            transition: border-color 0.5s;

            &:hover {
                border-color: $medium-color;
            }

            &.current {
                border-color: $main-color;
            }
        }
    }

    //HEADER
    #header {
        //HEADER HOME WHOLE
        &-home {
            background: $bg-image no-repeat center right / cover;
            color: #fff;

            //HEADER CONTENT
            .header-content {
                padding-top: 20%;
                text-align: center;

                h1 {
                    font-size: 4rem;
                    line-height: 1.2;
                }
            }
        }
        // HEADER INNER PAGES CONTENT
        &-inner {
            background: $bg-image no-repeat 20% 30% / cover;
            height: 5.5rem;
            border-bottom: 3px solid $main-color;
        }
    }

    //HOME SECTIONS
    #home {
        //HOME SECTION A

        &-a {
            padding-top: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20rem;

            .container {
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
            }

            .specials {
                margin-top: 1rem 0;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 1rem;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

                .fas {
                    color: $main-color;
                    padding-bottom: 0.8rem;
                }
            }
        }

        //HOME SECTION B

        &-b {
            height: 300px;

            .container {
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .stats {
                height: 100%;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

                li {
                    padding-top: 2rem;
                    line-height: 1;

                    &.stats-title {
                        font-size: 2rem;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }

                    &.stats-numbers {
                        font-size: 1.5rem;
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }
                }

                div {
                    padding: 2rem 0;
                    margin: 0;

                    &:nth-child(odd) {
                        background: $light-color;
                    }

                    &:nth-child(even) {
                        background: $medium-color;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        &-c {
            margin-top: 50px;
            height: 500px;
            .container {
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
            }

            .process {
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 3rem;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
                text-align: center;

                &-step {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    font-size: 28px;
                    background: $main-color;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    height: 15px;
                    width: 15px;
                    line-height: 15px;
                    padding: 1rem;
                    transition: all 1s;
                }
                //PROCESS ICON
                &-icon {
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    background: $dark-color;
                    color: #fff;
                    padding: 2rem;
                    width: 70px;
                    height: 70px;
                    line-height: 70px;
                    text-align: center;
                    position: relative;
                    transition: all 1s;

                    &:hover {
                        background: $main-color;
                        width: 90px;
                        height: 90px;
                        line-height: 90px;

                        .process-step {
                            background: $dark-color;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // FOOTER

    #main-footer {

        background: $dark-color;
        color: #fff;
        height: 6rem;

        .footer-content {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: 6rem;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .social .fab {
            margin: 1rem;
            border: 2px #fff solid;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            line-height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.5rem;

            &:hover {
                background: $main-color;
            }
        }
    }
```

config.scss code

```
    //VARIABLES
    $website-width:1280px;
    $main-color:#ffbc00;
    $light-color: #f4f4f4;
    $medium-color:#ccc;
    $dark-color:#333;
    $bg-image:url('../images/main.jpg');

//SET TEXT COLOR FUNCTION 

    @function set-text-color($color) {
    @if(lightness($color) > 50 ) {
        @return #000 ;
    }
    @else {
        @return #fff;
    }
    }
```

utilities.scss code :

```
    .container {
    max-width: $website-width;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0 350px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

//BUTTONS
    %btn-shared {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .btn {

    &-main {
        @extend %btn-shared;
        color: #333;
        background-color: $main-color;
    }

    &-light {
        @extend %btn-shared;
        color: #333;
        background-color: $light-color;
    }

    &-dark {
        @extend %btn-shared;
        color: #f4f4f4;
        background-color: $dark-color;
    }
    }

    button[class^='btn-']:hover,
    a[class^='btn-']:hover,
    input[class^='btn-']:hover {
    background-color: $main-color;
    }

// ABOUT BACKGROUNDS 
    .bg {
    &-main {
        background: $main-color;
        color: set-text-color($main-color);
    }
    &-dark {
        background: $dark-color;
        color: set-text-color($dark-color);
    }
    &-light {
        background: $light-color;
        color: set-text-color($light-color);
    }
    &-medium {
        background: $medium-color;
        color: set-text-color($medium-color);
    }
    }

    .lead {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .text-center {
    text-align: center;
    }

//PADDING 
    .py {
    &-1 {
        padding: 1rem 0;
    }
    &-2 {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }
    &-3 {
        padding: 3rem 0;
    }
    &-4 {
        padding: 4rem 0;
    }
    }


//MARGIN 
    .my {
    &-1 {
        margin: 1rem 0;
    }
    &-2 {
        margin: 2rem 0;
    }
    &-1 {
        margin: 3rem 0;
    }
    &-1 {
        margin: 4rem 0;
    }
}


.section-title {
    font-size: 2rem ;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .bottom-line {
    height: 2px;
    width: 3rem;
    background: $main-color;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
    }
```

The code related to item_grid.scss is completely unrelated to this page. Thank you for the help.

Comment: have you tried giving the #mainfooter a margin-top?

Comment: Can you use the embed code snippet option to provide us a running example?

Comment: @HadiPawar Yeah, i tried that earlier i was using that only to make it look proper but when i made other tabs the page the same issue happened and i decided to look for some other way to solve it out. Moreover, by using top-margin on the footer makes it look not so good on some pages. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Santosh I am sorry for the trouble it's the very first time i am posting a question the website so i didn't have much idea how to do so. I will try doing embedding code snippet option. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Santosh i have added an image of the website how it looks as i was unable to use embed code snippet. Hope this gives some insight of the trouble.

Comment: why not stick it to the bottom?

Comment: @HadiPawar stick it to the bottom ? meaning ? If using sticky footer(i don't want to use that).

Comment: why not is my question? footers and headers are supposed to stick there you dont want them moving around if the content on the page changes?

Comment: @HadiPawar i am sorry i didn't understand you there. I just want to remove the white-space down the footer without modifying the structure of the page or my only last option is to increase the size of the divs( by modifying the structure) i have used as the sections.

Comment: increasing the size of the div is not a wise option is it can change and there is no way you can predict the dynamic content. Try my answer below and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this out and it just sticks the footer to the whole page and it never disappears even if i scroll up which looks very undesirable.